How to reduce notches in input AC voltage for Totempole Power factor Correction circuit?
Respected readers, I am working with a totem pole PFC circuit. In an experimental study, I face a problem of high-frequency notches in source voltage (Yellow one). I found an explanation behind this. It happens because of source inductance, which gives an L(di/dt) effect at the switching frequency. Is this problem inevitable or is there a solution for it? Please give me a suggestion for it. I will be thankful to you.

Are you using GaN FETs for the high frequency switches? If not, the reverse recovery losses and spikes/EMI are horrific for the body diodes of conventional FETs in a totem-pole PFC.  A schematic and more details may help get a better answer.

Show the schematic and the points you get the measurements across.

The layout might be helpful as well- Using integrated driver/FET GaN can help, or at least GaN FETs with Kelvin connections to the source for the driver.  But in the absence of a schematic and layout it's difficult to do anything but make general suggestions.

Please post schematics and indicate scope probe locations.  Photos are also helpful.  Is this a real-world measurement, or a simulation?

I am using SiC MOSFET and the problem of reverse recovery is not present here. This is a real-world experimental study. I am measuring the autotransformer output voltage which is fed to drive the PFC. The results are captured by Power Analyzer. This is an interleaved PFC and the switching frequency is around 25 kHz only. The layout is bit messy as it is an experimental prototype.

I am not using Kelvin Source SiC, it is a simple three-terminal SiC. The driver is not closely placed, the pulses are fed through jumper wires. However, I am more concerned about the notches in input voltage. There are minimal spikes at the output voltage (Pink one). So, the reverse recovery issue is absent. I have also checked the individual switch's current profile and there is no spike. However, there are notches in the input AC voltage. I request you to give me suggestions to remove those notches on the AC side. @John D

It's not obvious what's causing your input spikes, but a totem-pole PFC requires a very careful layout on a PCB, minimizing parasitics.  It also requires careful gate drive signals and timing.  Until you have those things as a starting point it will be hard to optimize performance.  A gate driver far from the FET hooked up with jumper wires is not a good way to prototype a PFC.
